# SoapUi Script Groovy

Tags: properties, testcase

I have a TestSuite that I named **ComplexTestSuite**.

In this TestSuite a TestCase  is named **Operation**.

I add a property  (subscriberId) in this **Operation**.

And I add soap request that i named **GET TEST1** :

```
<SubscriberId> $ {Properties # SubscriberId} </ SubscriberId>
```

If I have more than one subscriberId value, how do i execute all these values to one click?

Comment: I have this code for one value of  subscriberId  :

Comment: log.info("Chargement des propriétés à partir du fichier MSISDN.txt")

Comment: props = new java.util.Properties()

Comment: fis = new FileInputStream("c:/MSISDN.txt")

Comment: props.load(fis)

Comment: subscriberId = props.getProperty("MSISDN")

Comment: targetStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties")

Comment: targetStep.setPropertyValue("subscriberId", subscriberId)

Comment: log.info("subscriberId : " + subscriberId)